# Looping through a list adding values to dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 4 dictionaries. I also have a list of 36 values. I'm trying to loop through the list of dictionaries, filling each dictionary with the list values in ascending order having item 1 as the key, 2 & 3 as the value attached and so on. The final result being 4 dictionaries, each with three keys and each key having two values attached. 
The end result would be

```
dict1={x:(7,4),y:(7,8),z:(7:22)}
dict2={x: (111,4),y:(111,8),z:(111:22)} 
...
```

Currently I have the following which does not work.

```
my_list = ['x',7,4,'y',7,8,'z',7,22,'x',111,4,'y',111,8,'z',111,22 and so on]

dict1={}
dict2={}
dict3={}
dict4={}
my_dict_list=[dict1,dict2,dict3,dict4]

for dicts in my_dict_list:
    for x in range (0,len(my_list),3):
        dicts[my_list[x]] = my_list[x+1],my_list[x+2]
        break
```

the output of that code being the first 3 items in my list, in all four of the dictionaries. As so:

```
>>> dict_1
{'x': (7, 4)}
>>> dict_2
{'x': (7, 4)}
>>> dict_3
{'x': (7, 4)}
>>> dict_4
{'x': (7, 4)}
```

I think this is the closest I've got so far as it is actually filling each dictionary, previously I've only managed to fill the first dictionary and other similar wrong scenarios. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's not the output of the code you've posted; due to the break, it would completely fill only the first of the dictionaries. Give a [mcve]. That said, if you want them to all be the same why not fill one then copy it three times?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for pointing that out and apologies. I will amend when i get home. Also thanks for the link to minimum reproducible examples! I do not want them to be all the same, the keys will be the same although values will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_list = ['x',7,4,'y',7,8,'z',7,22,'x',111,4,'y',111,8,'z',111,22]

my_dict_list = []

idx = 0
current_dict = {}
while idx < len(my_list):
    key, *vals = my_list[idx : idx + 3]

    # If key repeats, starting a new current_dict, old one adding to my_dict_list
    if key in current_dict:
        my_dict_list.append(current_dict)
        current_dict = {}

    current_dict[key] = vals

    idx += 3

if current_dict:
    my_dict_list.append(current_dict)

print(my_dict_list)
```

In the solution above we loop `my_list` reading 3 values at a time. And in case if key of a dictionary is repeated this is interpreted and a starting of a new dictionary so the old one must be stored in `my_dict_list`.